# Make an Ajax request on tab change in Sencha Touch 2

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, extjs, sencha-touch

I'm working in sencha touch 2.4 and I want an ajax request on specified tab with the tab id. 
How can I call my ajax function or I can get a request only on the click on the specified tab by tab id? I'm using `Ext.define` to define my package and app view.

**My Code:**

```
config: {
        tabBarPosition: 'bottom',

        items: [

     {
                    id: 'tab',
                    title: 'Home',
                    iconCls: 'home',
                    styleHtmlContent: true,
                    scrollable: true,
                    items: {
                        docked: 'top',
                        xtype: 'titlebar',
                        title: 'MyTab'
                    }
                }
]
}
```

**My request function:**

```
request: function() {
            Ext.Ajax.request({
            url: 'http://www.example.com'
            method: 'GET',
            callback: function(options, success, response) {
                Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#id')[0].setHtml( response.responseText );
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To detect when a tab has been selected you can either listen to when that particular tab receives focus using the panels focus event or you can listen to the [`activeitemchanged`](http://docs-origin.sencha.com/touch/2.4/2.4.1-apidocs/#!/api/Ext.tab.Panel-event-activeitemchange) event on the tabpanel, which will fire anytime a tab is selected. Code sample below:

```
Ext.create('Ext.TabPanel', {
        fullscreen: true,
        tabBarPosition: 'bottom',

        defaults: {
            styleHtmlContent: true
        },

        items: [{
            title: 'Home',
            iconCls: 'home',
            html: 'Home Screen'
        }, {
            title: 'Contact',
            iconCls: 'user',
            html: 'Contact Screen'
        }],
        listeners: {
            activeitemchange: function() {
                console.log('active item changed');
            }
        }
    });
```

To implement this you can either use `Ext.create` like I have above or you can use `Ext.define` to define the component and initialize it later with the create method.

Comment: I've updated the answer, sorry about that. Investigating why that wasn't working

Comment: I want to use Ext.define and not Ext.application.

Comment: Sorry I forgot this was for ST2, I was referring to ExtJs solutions. I have re-written the answer. You can use any method to initialize the code that you like. I have just used that to get a quick example running.

Comment: still not listening the event, I'm using Ext.define.

Comment: OK i've done with this solution, i was putting the listners inside the items array.

Comment: Great :) Glad to of helped

Comment: I'm also very much pleased to U, Thanks once again.